# how to start an interactive shell with special setup

Tags: cygwin, zsh, interactive

I want to start an interactive zsh (on cygwin) with project specific set-up:

1. source `/etc/profile`
2. source `~/.profile`
3. source `$PROJECT_HOME/Setup.zsh`
4. become interactive

I got as far a step 3 but then the shell just terminates.

I have done this kind of thing before but I forgot how I did it. I tried to google for it but could not find anything. Probalby a case of having the wrong search terms.

Adding `$PROJECT_HOME/Setup.zsh` to `~/.profile` is of course no solution as the idea is to have multiple start-up icons on the windows desktop to start shells for one of many project.

Comment: A zsh usually does not **become** interactive, but you usually start it **as** an interactive shell. zsh then processes several startup files; pick one of them and source the files where you have stored your necessary definitions. The information you need is in the chapter _STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES_ in the _zshall_ man page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your shortcuts look like:

```
env PROJECT_HOME=~/projects/this zsh

env PROJECT_HOME=~/projects/that zsh
```

Sourcing `$PROJECT_HOME/Setup.zsh` will work fine now.

Comment: Actually more like `env PROJECT_HOME=~/projects/that zsh  --login -i $PROJECT_HOME/Setup.zsh` — After which the shell just ends instead of becoming interactive. I think there is an option missing but I can't find out which one. — The idea is to set it up a start icon so I don't need to type the source command manually

Comment: I said *sourcing* `$PROJECT_HOME/Setup.zsh` -- as in, from your `~/.zshrc` -- not running from the command line.

Comment: I see what you mean: `c:\cygwin\bin\env.exe PROJECT_HOME=/Work/projects/this /bin/zsh`. Yes that could work with some fine tuning. I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

zsh doesn't support this very well. The only way I've ever known for doing this is to temporarily override `$ZDOTDIR` to some temporary directory and stick a `.zshrc` in there that can load the functions you want. Here's a full example:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh

dir=`mktemp -d /tmp/adevXXX`

# Preload the shell with all of the shell functions defined in
# build/envsetup.sh.
cat >$dir/.zshrc <<EOF
source $HOME/.zshrc
source build/envsetup.sh
EOF
ZDOTDIR=$dir zsh

rm -r $dir
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not say how you define what you call  *multiple start-up icons*, and how exactly you start your terminal with the shell. For instance, on my platform I am using `minnty`, and you can for a certain desktop icon put into the properties a startup command something like

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -s 101,26 -e /usr/bin/dash -c "PROJECT=25 /usr/bin/zsh -i -l"
```

and inside your .zshrc, you decide on the value of `$PROJECT`, which project specific settings to load.

In this approach, I use an interim shell (in my case: dash, because it loads quickly) to setup the environment variable and finally call zsh as interactive login shell.

The same approach should also work with other Terminal emulators, such as ConEmu.